# How to check validation of value range of radNumericTextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

How to check validation of value range of radNumericTextBox ? I want to stop insert , when I enter incorrect value in radNumericTextBox. When I enter incorrect value in radNumericTextBox , and click on btnInsert, controls change value into 0 and save.

My code is:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" ValidationGroup="oppSub" DisplayMode="List" />
    <div dir="rtl">
        <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txtDiscount" Type="Percent" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100"
            AllowOutOfRangeAutoCorrect="false" ShowSpinButtons="true"
            ValidationGroup="oppSub"
            runat="server">
            <NumberFormat KeepNotRoundedValue="false" DecimalDigits="3" DecimalSeparator="."
                AllowRounding="false"></NumberFormat>
        </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>

        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" Text="save" runat="server"
            ValidationGroup="oppSub"></asp:Button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate a telerik RadNumericTextBox you need a range validator.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="NumericTextBoxRangeValidator" 
                    runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtDiscount"
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter in a number between 0 and 100." 
                    Display="Dynamic"
                    MaximumValue="100" MinimumValue="0" Type="Decimal">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

This will alert the user that they have entered and invalid date and prompt for another.

See [Telerik's example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/input/examples/common/validation/defaultcs.aspx) of the validator at work

Comment: ok. I set this validator in my page. But Type="Persent" is Invalid. Why?

Comment: @user3628391 `Integer` is what it should be.  I mistakenly put percent.  The validator doesnt care that its a percent value in the text box, it just looks to validate the value.

Comment: @user3628391 What type of number are you putting in the box?  Your type should match the type of the validator.  If you are putting in `2.00`, then it will fail because that is a `Double` or `Decimal`.

Comment: Type of radnumerictextbox is percent

Comment: it way is work correctly. But InValid style of radNumericTextBox is not work

Comment: @user3628391, leave the RadNumericTextBox as a `PERCENT` type, but put the validator as a `DECIMAL`

Comment: DecimalType for validation is invalid